# Errors locating elements with Ruby Watir and PhantomJS

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir

I have a script that runs perfectly in the ChromeWebDriver but fails on PhantomJS.  When I check if an element exists i get the following error:

> [ERROR - 2014-01-07T19:31:55.878Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - El
>   ement(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1389123115867

This doesn't really seem like an issue as the script continues.  However, later on the script will fail unable to locate the following element:

> question.div(:class => "choices")

This particular script visits a page that has test questions on it.  They are in random order.  The script decided what kind of question it is and chooses a random answer.

Thanks for any help. Here is the relevant code:

```
def QuestionType(question)
    if question.div(:class => "questionPrompt").text_field.exists?
        puts "FITB"
        FITB(question)
    #elsif question.div(:class => "choices").ul(:class =>"choices-list").li(:index => 1).checkbox.exists?
    elsif question.checkbox.exists?
        puts "Checkbox"
        Checkbox(question)
    else
        puts "Radio"
        Radio(question)
    end

end

def FITB(question)
    arn = Random.new.rand(0..10)
    if arn == 0
        answers.li(:index => arn).radio.set
    else
        idx = 0
        begin
            question.div(:class => "questionPrompt").text_field(:index => idx).set("Test #{idx}")
            idx = idx + 1;
        end while question.div(:class => "questionPrompt").text_field(:index => idx).exists?
    end
    puts "FITB Complete"
end

def Checkbox(question)
    allAnswers = question.div(:class => "choices")
    answers = allAnswers.ul

    max = answers.lis.length - 1
    arn = Random.new.rand(0..max)
    if arn == 0
        answers.li(:index => arn).radio.set
    else
        for i in 1..arn
            answers.li(:index => i).checkbox.set
        end
    end
    puts "Checkbox Complete"
end

def Radio(question)
    allAnswers = question.div(:class => "choices")
    answers = allAnswers.ul

    max = answers.lis.length - 1
    arn = Random.new.rand(0..max)

    answers.li(:index => arn).radio.set

    puts "Radio Complete"
end
```

Comment: Are you on windows? Which website page you are trying to automate? share HTML of that page? Have you tried `xpath`?